# How to test website on older versions of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, web

I am in need to test my website on older versions of **Chrome**. There are number of tools available that offers to test on older versions IE.

IE itself allows to test in its older versions.

But how do I the same for older versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

There are several options, some that I know are:

1. Use [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) to grab screenshots of your site that have been rendereed in a wide variety of browsers and versions. This is limited to screenshots only.
2. Create separate user accounts on your computer and install a different version of Chrome for each user.
3. Create several VMs, either on your computer or via a cloud service, and fire one up per version.
4. Try a cloud emulation server, such as [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) - there are many others, but this is one we considered using at work. This is a paid service.

If you are testing professionally, a cloud emulation service as per option 4 is your best choice out for efficiency. There could be some other options around.

Comment: This is still a relevant question 8 years later!

BrowserShots seems to not be running anymore, so an alternative is browserling (https://www.browserling.com/). That worked like an absolute charm in terms of a free service and for extremely quick testing of a site in older versions of browsers.